# Galaxy S4 and libmedia.so killing Flash

Tags: android, flash, galaxy

I'm trying to grasp what's actually happening still but the short of it is I have a WebView which tries to load a flash file (audio/video embed) then hangs for a moment before the entire app crashes to the home screen.

I do understand flash is no longer officially supported but to my knowledge for the moment Flash still sideloads fine even on other devices that are current.

After getting a hold of a person with an S4 and grabbing the adb log output I've come across something about Android that's over my head.  It seems to say that Flash plugin is attempting to use /system/lib/libmedia.so and runs into an error that ends it completely.  Our whole app goes with it however instead of ending up with a blank WebView.

The player embed is actually correctly loading on the S4 up until it tries to play.  In the first trial no crash occurred and the video played fine but lacked any audio.   Then relaunching the app for a second trial (and every time after) it would instead run into this error and crash the app entirely.

(Here's a condensed paste of the stack/log that I have.  I'm trimming off a lot on the top that's just a few hundred lines of raw memory.)

```
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762): Build: samsung/jfltespr/jfltespr:4.2.2/JDQ39/L720VPUAMDL:user/release-keys
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762): Hardware: MSM8960
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762): Revision: 11
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762): Bootloader: L720VPUAMDL
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762): Radio: unknown
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762): Kernel: Linux version 3.4.0-529760 (se.infra@SEP-107) (gcc version 4.6.x-google 20120106 (prerelease) (GCC) ) #1 SMP PREEMPT Sat Apr 27 18:12:21 KST 2013
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762): Build fingerprint: 'samsung/jfltespr/jfltespr:4.2.2/JDQ39/L720VPUAMDL:user/release-keys'
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762): Revision: '11'
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762): pid: 26307, tid: 26445, name: FP_SoundMixPoll  >>> {package_name} <<<
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0000011e
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):     r0 0000011e  r1 70d6fbb0  r2 00000001  r3 74ffded7
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):     r4 0000011e  r5 00000086  r6 00000004  r7 7c1c2000
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):     r8 7c1c2000  r9 795d9341  sl 79a6c068  fp 7c1c3d30
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):     ip 40e35c28  sp 7fa79d00  lr 40dec31b  pc 402926f8  cpsr 20000010
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):     d0  e636e262e4ede0a8  d1  e30de5a4e57ce5af
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):     d2  e1cde7efe150e5da  d3  e4ace1bbe371e65d
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):     d4  e640e57de585e16d  d5  e4ebe7cce608e7f6
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):     d6  e525e756e494e755  d7  e602e9d3e55ce84f
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):     d8  41d46943ec4309a6  d9  41d46943ec463cd9
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):     d16 f754f627f520f4e5  d17 f7bbf60df810f6e0
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):     d18 f4f2f89bf676f700  d19 f7fbf7f0f57ef7ec
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):     d20 f71bf799f90cf96e  d21 f4b6f485f4acf3bc
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):     d22 f73ffbc6f67df961  d23 f6c2f746f6e2f9d8
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):     d24 0000000000000000  d25 0000000000000000
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):     d26 3ff0000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):     d28 0000000000000000  d29 0000000000000000
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):     d30 0000000000000000  d31 0000000000000000
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):     scr 6800001b
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762): backtrace:
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):     #00  pc 0000d6f8  /system/lib/libc.so
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):     #01  pc 0004c317  /system/lib/libmedia.so
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):     #02  pc 0004c57f  /system/lib/libmedia.so (android::AudioTrack::stopped() const+10)
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):     #03  pc 0053fb35  /data/app-lib/com.adobe.flashplayer-1/libflashplayer.so
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762): stack:
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):          7fa79cc0  40292898  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_mutex_lock)
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):          7fa79cc4  7c1c3d40  
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):          7fa79cc8  79a6c068  /data/app-lib/com.adobe.flashplayer-1/libflashplayer.so
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):          7fa79ccc  7c1c3a04  
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):          7fa79cd0  7c1c3d40  
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):          7fa79cd4  798645cd  /data/app-lib/com.adobe.flashplayer-1/libflashplayer.so
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):          7fa79cd8  7c1c3d40  
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):          7fa79cdc  7950b867  /data/app-lib/com.adobe.flashplayer-1/libflashplayer.so
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):          7fa79ce0  7c1c3d40  
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):          7fa79ce4  7984ff75  /data/app-lib/com.adobe.flashplayer-1/libflashplayer.so
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):          7fa79ce8  7c1c2000  
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):          7fa79cec  79a6c068  /data/app-lib/com.adobe.flashplayer-1/libflashplayer.so
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):          7fa79cf0  7c1c39d4  
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):          7fa79cf4  00000060  
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):          7fa79cf8  df002777  
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):          7fa79cfc  e3a070ad  
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):     #00  7fa79d00  74ffded7  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):          7fa79d04  0000011e  
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):          7fa79d08  00000086  
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):          7fa79d0c  00000004  
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):          7fa79d10  7c1c2000  
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):          7fa79d14  40dec31b  /system/lib/libmedia.so
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):     #01  7fa79d18  74ffded7  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):          7fa79d1c  40dec583  /system/lib/libmedia.so (android::AudioTrack::stopped() const+14)
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):     #02  7fa79d20  74ffded7  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):          7fa79d24  7c1c3d00  
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):          7fa79d28  7c1c3a20  
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):          7fa79d2c  7984fb37  /data/app-lib/com.adobe.flashplayer-1/libflashplayer.so
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):     #03  7fa79d30  71c28fa0  
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):          7fa79d34  79a6c068  /data/app-lib/com.adobe.flashplayer-1/libflashplayer.so
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):          7fa79d38  00005ecc  
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):          7fa79d3c  7c1c3d00  
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):          7fa79d40  7c1c3d48  
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):          7fa79d44  7c1c2000  
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):          7fa79d48  79ac1bb4  
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):          7fa79d4c  7c1c3d60  
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):          7fa79d50  7983fcd5  /data/app-lib/com.adobe.flashplayer-1/libflashplayer.so
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):          7fa79d54  000097ec  
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):          7fa79d58  00009b94  
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):          7fa79d5c  00007be0  
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):          7fa79d60  4278f501  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):          7fa79d64  00003204  
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):          7fa79d68  ec4309a6  
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):          7fa79d6c  41d46943  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762): memory near r1:
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):     70d6fb90 402cfc64 402cfc64 00000028 00000013  
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):     70d6fba0 61776c61 ea007379 e1a00000 00000033  
05-28 16:12:33.722: D/CrashAnrDetector(762):     70d6fbb0 0000
```

The one line with `android::AudioTrack::stopped() const+14` is what stands out to me but I'll tack on I'm not familiar with this kind of output for a bug.  I searched around about libmedia.so and my understanding so far is that different roms might have different versions of this library and whatever flash uses it for has been changed in the S4.  Could be audio or video I suppose but I did have a trail where video somehow worked fine in silence.

So is it that Samsung modified (and seemingly broke) a library of Android in their stock rom or am I greatly misunderstanding this?   At the moment it looks like I can't do anything to fix our app but I don't even know, what does all this mean?

Answer (score 1):

I found this info
"Apparently, the stock browser in Galaxy S4 was altered by Samsung to block Flash plugin and other plugins as well." 
From this link
http://allaboutgalaxys4.com/how-to-install-flash-on-galaxy-s4-and-make-it-work/
I know it's not an answer, but at least now I know why I can not get flash to play.